# Error message when dropping constrain

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, alter, sql-drop

Every time I want to drop a constraint from a column I get an error. I can't see the problem. I am using postgres.

So I have created a table with two columns:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA(
person_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
lastname CHAR(100)
)
```

I use the code

```
ALTER TABLE TableA DROP CONSTRAINT person_id
```

to DROP the constraint from person_id but then I get an error:

```
Error : ERROR:  constraint "person_id" of relation "tablea" does not exist
```

What's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that postgresql hasn't named the constraint this way...

Comment: Just a side note: I'm pretty sure you do *not* want `CHAR` but you want `VARCHAR` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primary keys in PostgreSQL are by default called `<table>_pkey`, so you probably want something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE TableA DROP CONSTRAINT TableA_pkey;
```

You can check the names for example in `psql` using `\d TableA`.

Answer (score 0):

That means that you choose wrong name of constraint - you choose column name instead of constraint